# What permissions need to be set after Xammp (installer) using virtual hosts after Big Sur upgrade?

Tags: php, xampp, macos-big-sur

I finally got round to upgrading to Big Sur and boy did it ruin my day. (Ubuntu here I come)

I had to reinstall Xammp (Installer not VM) but I cannot get Xammp to work with any of my Worpdress projects. I'm using a virtual host

I've tried making the XAMMP folder writeable by everyone and added myself as a user, I chmoded -R the html folder with the wordpress in. Googling the issues suggests it's a permission issue I believe it's a permissions (symlinks possibly)  but I'm not sure which permissions need to be changed.

`Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Users/tristanb/Documents/Clients/Ferrai/html/index.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my virtual hosts pointed to files in the `/Documents` folder which with the upgrade had had the permissions altered. I moved my webfiles to a new folder `/Users/tristanb/Clients/` and updated the `httpd-vhosts.conf`.